# Interface handling in Simple XML framework with guice

Tags: guice, simple-framework

[Simple](http://simple.sourceforge.net) can not handle Interfaces out of the box:

```
org.simpleframework.xml.core.InstantiationException: Cannot
instantiate interface com.bitplan.restmodelmanager.Package for
interface com.bitplan.restmodelmanager.Package  at
org.simpleframework.xml.core.ObjectFactory.getInstance(ObjectFactory.java:68)
```

The Sourcecode of ObjectFactory (see below) seems to indicate that a Strategy could resolve the class for the interface. IMHO a guice injector could be used here. What would be a good (possibly existing) solution for such a Strategy?

```java
   /**
    * This method will instantiate an object of the field type, or if
    * the <code>Strategy</code> object can resolve a class from the
    * XML element then this is used instead. If the resulting type is
    * abstract or an interface then this method throws an exception.
    * 
    * @param node this is the node to check for the override
    * 
    * @return this returns an instance of the resulting type
    */       
   @Override
   public Instance getInstance(InputNode node) throws Exception {
      Value value = getOverride(node);
      Class expect = getType();

      if(value == null) { 
         if(!isInstantiable(expect)) {
            throw new InstantiationException("Cannot instantiate %s for %s", expect, type);              
         }
         return context.getInstance(expect);         
      }
      return new ObjectInstance(context, value);      
   }
```